# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(\tan(x+\pi/4))^{1/3}-1}{\sin(2x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(\tan(x+\pi/4))^{1/3}-1}{\sin(2x)}$$
I know the limit is $1\over3$ by looking at the graph of the function, but how can I algebraically show that that is the limit. using this limit: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+x)^c -1}{x} =c$$? (without L'Hopital Rule)

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(\tan(x+\pi/4))^{1/3}-1}{\sin2x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1+\tan(x+\pi/4)-1)^{1/3}-1}{\tan(x+π/4)−1}\cdot\frac{\tan(x+π/4)−1}{\sin 2x}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1+\tan x}{1-\tan x}-1}{\sin 2x}=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\tan x}{2\sin x\cos x}=\frac{1}{3}\cdot1=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: You had written $1$ as the final answer. I have taken liberty to correct that. And by the way nice approach +1.

Comment: A silly distraction :(. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of derivative:  $$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$$  Second hint:  multiply numerator and denominator by $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x \to 0}{\tan^{1/3}(x + \pi/4) - 1 \over \sin\pars{2x}}
=\half\lim_{x \to 0}\bracks{{2x \over \sin\pars{2x}}\,
{\tan^{1/3}(\pi/4 + x) - 1 \over x}}
\\[3mm]&=\half\lim_{x \to 0}\bracks{{\tan^{1/3}(\pi/4 + x) - 1 \over x}}
=
\left.\half\,\totald{\tan^{1/3}\pars{x}}{x}\right\vert_{x\ =\ \pi/4}
=
\half\,\bracks{{1 \over 3}\,\tan^{-2/3}\pars{x}\sec^{2}\pars{x}}_{x\ =\ \pi/4}
\\[3mm]&= {1 \over 3}
\end{align}
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\lim_{x \to 0}{\tan^{1/3}(x + \pi/4) - 1 \over \sin\pars{2x}}
= {1 \over 3}}$$